# Hide/Show Header On Small Screens, But Keep On Bigger Screen Jquery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently adding a Hamburger Bar to my mobile website. I can get the stuff to disappear currently, and then show again. Problem is when I hide/show the divs, it messed up the website on larger screens.

After I hide my menu from the Hamburger button, the header on larger screens then go away. How could I make the Hamburger button show/hide only the header on SMALL screens? Here is my code:

HTML

```
<span id="headerdisplaybuttonsxs" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"> </span>
<span id="headerdisplayloginxs" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span>
<div id="headerrightside">Content</div>
<div id="headerleftside">Other Content</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#headerdisplaybuttonsxs').click(function() {
    if($('#headerrightside').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#headerleftside').hide();
        $('#headerrightside').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#headerrightside').hide();
    }
});

$('#headerdisplayloginxs').click(function() {
    if($('#headerleftside').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#headerrightside').hide();
        $('#headerleftside').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#headerleftside').hide();
    }
});
```

**So basically how I make the Hamburger Bar only hide/show the divs with a media query of 767px or less?**

Answer (score 1):

Set your toggle button to `display:none` on larger screens.

CSS:

```
    @media (min-width:768px) {
      #headerdisplaybuttonsxs { display:none; }
    }
    @media (max-width:767px) {
      #headerdisplaybuttonsxs { display:inline; }
    }
```

Comment: This needs to be done through JS/Jquery though. The problem is it is affecting all media queries, and not just one.

Comment: but that doesn't mean that he has to use js to do that. JS is the last resort when it comes to media query. He should either clean up his mark up or re think his logic instead of using media queries in js.

Comment: Basically I think none of you understand my question :( Basically when I am setting a div to `display: none` I would just like it to affect media queries that are LESS then 768px. Problem is it is affecting all sizes..

Comment: If your media query is 'affecting all sizes,' you're not writing it properly. Could you post what you've tried, please?

Comment: That is the problem, I have no clue on how to make JQuery only target certain media queries :(

Comment: You don't *need* to use jQuery to target media queries -- you can use CSS to display/hide what the jQuery is triggered by. Have you tried to implement my answer?

Comment: That is what I am doing currently, still overrides everything

Comment: What do you mean by 'overrides everything'?

Comment: When .show() is called it sets all media queries to display, when it is hide() everything is hidden, and I dont want everything hidden

Comment: Is this what you mean by media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: If your really have to conditionally run functions at different viewports, use miderbizr mq method

Answer (score 0):

`@media( max-width: 767px ) { #headerrightside { display: none; } }` :

hide `#headerrightside` for 767px and below.

Comment: Oh, good idea, just do this with CSS lol... xD I will test it out thank you

Comment: also use the `toggle` method instead of checking by hand if the display is none or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap there are built in classes hidden-** and visible-** to handle visibility at different sizes